# In Xamarin.Android getting resource id "Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException:" error occur

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to get id(int) for audio file from Asset folder but it give me error.

```
var File_Id = Resources.GetIdentifier("my_file.ogg","Assets", PackageName);
```

Above line of code execute in android **Service** 
it give error,

**Error Log:**

> 03-13 14:03:50.047 W/ResourceType(13170): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
>   Unhandled Exception:
>   Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

this file "my_file.ogg" is in "Asset" folder ,build action set to "AndroidAsset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset can be read using the `AssetsManager`. Try below code snippet to read file from asset.

```
Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.Assets.OpenFd("File name");
```

**Updated Answer** :

The following code snippet will help to play media file directly from the Asset folder.

```
Android.Content.Res.AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.Assets.OpenFd(fullPath);
     if  (afd != null )
     {
         player.SetDataSource (afd.FileDescriptor, afd.StartOffset, afd.Length);
         player.Prepare ();
         player.Start ();
     }
```

Comment: thanks for answer but actually i need id of resource not stream,because i need to pass it to MediaPlayer.Create(context,Resources.GetIdentifier(""f.mp3","Assets", PackageName)),  id can get from Java.IO.File it need java stream not system stream

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6671/example-code-about-playing-a-video-from-an-asset-with-videoview

Comment: Check this link. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot man.code in link helped me, while using setDataSource(..) method instead setting file in MediaPlayer.Create("","",pkgName)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a Xamarin Forms project. I had included a resource in the iOS project which the xaml page was referring to, but forgot to include it in the Android project.